# Absolute position is not allowing my link to display

Tags: css, html, position

i have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/375Z3/) which as you can see when you hover of the Link the Hidden link should display but because of the position absolute it doesnt. Any idea how to make the link display without changing the `position: absolute`

I tried `z-index` to no go

Comment: Where do you want the Hidden link to be positioned? Right now it's set to top:100%, which places it at the very bottom of the page. Is that where it's supposed to be?

Comment: @David but its overwritten by `ul:hover {display:block;}`

Comment: @TomášTomííkBlatný Ah didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

The hidden link has `position: absolute;` and `top: 100%;`, so it displays 100% from top (thats why scrollbar appears after hover). Change the `top` property to something different and you will see the result.

Comment: +1 And furthermore, make it so that you can *click* the link, as right now, you won't be able to hover over Link 1 and click the hidden link at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The link are displayed, but in the bottom of the page,  if you change the CSS you must see the link:

```
.wrapper .nav ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
top: 10px;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually appearing; however, it's relative to the previous element in the hierarchy that has a relative position.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 33px;
  position:relative;
}
```

I'm not sure which element you want it relative to. In my example, I made it relative to your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

In your css **.wrapper .nav ul {}**, you have the **top: 100%;**. If you change that to say, **100px**, it shows. Of course position it where you want by adjusting the pixels.